# Define Proxy settings GNOME3

Tags: networking, gnome, proxy, gsettings

Last month I created a script I use to connect to a SOCKS proxy, when I ran the following commands -

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode manual
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host 127.0.0.1
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 9001
```

It would enable the system wide proxy and everything worked as expected. I'm not sure what changed between then and now, but these settings no longer change anything on the system.

Even when I monitor `gsettings`, and flip the proxy on manually through the GUI, I'm no longer seeing anything come across when I run -

```
gsettings monitor org.gnome.system.proxy
```

Whereas, previously I was seeing output which enabled me to figure out the syntax to change these settings. I must emphasize, when I enable this through GUI, it still works fine, but I'm trying to change these settings through my script. What can I do? Has there been some system update that broke this?

Comment: Did you run `gsettings` using `sudo` at some point? Does `find ~ . ! -user $USER` return anything related to `dconf`, `gsettings` or GNOME?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried running it with sudo but no difference.

Comment: Sorry, the first part wasn't a suggestion - it was a question. You shouldn't run `gsettings` with `sudo`!

Comment: No I dont think I did that prior to it not working

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that might happen across this, we can simply use dconf for the same settings, dconf itself is the backend configuration tool for gsettings, im still not sure why gsettings functionality broke

Equivalent dconf commands are -

```
dconf write /system/proxy/mode "'manual'"
dconf write /system/proxy/socks/host "'127.0.0.1'"
dconf write /system/proxy/socks/port "9001"
```